# Rotate image and apply physics for stop rotating slowly

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to rotate image by finger , and when user stop his finger then rotation will be stop slowly  . and user when rotating image then he can move image .

Rotation should be stop like pendulum ,

Answer (score 2):

You need to use UIView Animations and use one of the easing options. See the docs here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Set `yourView.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(90, 0, 0, 1);` where 90 is the the ammount you wish to rotate by in Radians.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation setDelegate:self];
animation.duration = 1.0;
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(mPreviousPoint.x, mCurrentPoint.y)]]; //FROM
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(mPreviousPoint.x, mPreviousPoint.y - mDegrees)]; //TO
[mLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

I'd used this to create a volume knob sortof thing which will rest at say position 4 or 5 if its placed between them based on the direction of rotation. (5 if in clockwise, 4 if in anticlockwise)